# Flattening a list of lists in OCaml

Tags: list, functional-programming, ocaml

I am implementing this hoemwork functionality using Ocaml:

- Not allowed to use `List` module
- the function has type `'a list list -> 'a list`
- the function return a list consisting of the lists in x concatenated together (just top level of lists is concatenated, unlike List.flatten)
- For example : `[[1,2,3],[45]] => [1,2,3,4,5]` and `[[[1,2,3],[4,5]],[[6,7]]] => [[1,2,3],[4,5],[6,7]]`

I am not sure where to start, can anyone give me some suggestion? Thank you

Comment: Just a comment: List.flatten just flattens the top level.  It doesn't flatten "extra deep".  You can actually figure this out from parametricity.  It has the type `'a list list -> 'a list` and so can't look inside the `'a` type for deeper list structure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't see the difference between `List.flatten` and your function.

To answer to your question: as usual with lists, try to think about the base cases:

- what do you do when you concatenate an empty list with something ?
- what do you do when you concatenate a non-empty list (with a head and a tail) with something ?

Wrap everything into a pattern match, cook it for few hours, and that's done :-)

Answer (score 2):

Thomas has given excellent advice.  Your basic operation is going to be to append one list to another.  It might help to write this function as a separate function first.  It will look something like this:

```
let rec myappend a b =
    match a with
    | [] -> (* Empty list prefixed to b (easy case) *)
    | ahead :: atail -> (* Recursive case *)
```

Armed with your own append function, you can carry out another level of recursion
to append all the top-level lists as Thomas suggests.